# AJAX driven "page complete" function? Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, mootools

This one might get me slaughtered, since I'm pretty sure it's bad coding practice, so here goes:

I have an AJAX driven site which loads both content and javascript in one go using Mootools' `Request.HTML`.

Since I have initialization scripts that need to be run to finish "setting up" the template, I include those in a function called `pageComplete()`, **on every page**

Visiting one page to another causes the previous `pageComplete()` function to no longer apply, since a new one is defined.

The javascript function that loads pages dynamically calls `pageComplete()` blindly when the AJAX call is completed and is loaded onto the page:

```
function loadPage(page, params) {
    // page is a string, params is a javascript object
    if (pageRequest && pageRequest.isRunning) pageRequest.cancel();
    pageRequest = new Request.HTML({
        url: '<?=APPLICATION_LINK?>' + page,
        evalScripts: true,
        onSuccess: function(tree, elements, html) {
            // Empty previous content and insert new content
            $('content').empty();
            $('content').innerHTML = html;
            pageComplete();
            pageRequest = null;
        }
    }).send('params='+JSON.encode(params));
}
```

So yes, if `pageComplete()` is not defined in one the pages, the *old* `pageComplete()` is called, which could potentially be disastrous, but as of now, every single page has `pageComplete()` defined, even if it is empty.

Good idea, bad idea?

Comment: Bad practice, just bind to domready rather then creating a global `pageComplete`

Comment: Can't. The DOM is already ready, since I am loading the page dynamically. setTimeouts are even worse, and fail when there is network congestion.

Comment: domready should be cached at the application level. You really should be firing immediatly if the DOM is already loaded. The content should bootstrap itself and don't even get me started on `.innerHTML = html`

Comment: Raynos, sorry if I'm being thick, but I don't seem to understand. Did you mean to suggest that I should create new events to domready on each template page? I cannot include the associated javascript code in the currently existing domready tag, since domready is called before the page loads, and the code would be meaningless.

Comment: Also, please do (if you have the time), expand on the faults behind `.innerHTML = html`... I'm always open to learning ;)

Comment: as for domready, use a small abstraction that keeps track whether domready has already fired. if it has you just invoke the dom ready callback you add immediatly, if it hasn't then wait for dom ready and fire the callback then. There are libraries for them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1590/discussion-between-raynos-and-julian-h-lam)

Answer (score 1):

You could place a line like

```
pageComplete=function(){};
```

somewhere in the code to make sure that the old function is not called for the new page. Possible places would be:

- First line of `loadPage`
- First line of `onSuccess`
- after the call `pageComplete();`

That said, it still smells.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way for `loadPage()` to know when the user has taken some action which should effectively cancel the loading of the first page. For example, if they click on a "page 1" button and you call `loadPage()` and they then click "page 2" while the remote resources are still loading, `loadPage()` needs to know that this has occurred.

A simple way to do this would be to check in the `onsuccess` handler if a global `pageName` variable still has the same value as it did when the request was fired, or perhaps Mootools offers a way to cancel any pending http requests which you can invoke when changing pages.

Comment: Hi matt b, the first line of the function achieves that. If the request is already set, then it becomes canceled and I start over,

Answer (score 0):

I see no purpose for `pageComplete()` in your example.  You already have `evalScripts` set to true.

- I doubt this concept would even work, because the browser is unlikely to have parsed `html` and inserted the new HTML by the next line, where `pageComplete()` is called.
- Both Prototype and (I'm fairly certain) jQuery have an alternative AJAX call that does the `.innerHTML = html` for you.  I'd be *very* surprised if mootools didn't.

Consider this template, which looks like something similar to what `html` would contain:

```
<div id='content1'>Stuff is here</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function pageComplete() {
      console.log('foo');
   }
</script>
```

Drop the function definition, and don't call `pageComplete()`.  This should work much better:

```
<div id='content1'>Stuff is here</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   console.log('foo');
</script>
```

`evalScripts` should run that javascript after the AJAX loads, without you having to fiddle around with redefining any functions.